# How to give rights to one user for the restart of a service

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, service, user-permissions

It's there a way i can give the rights to a specific user, for restart a specific service on windows server 2008 ?

Comment: Pretty much the same thing: http://serverfault.com/questions/15147/how-do-i-give-a-domain-user-permission-to-start-and-stop-a-tomcat-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give a domain user permission to start and stop a Tomcat service?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15147/how-do-i-give-a-domain-user-permission-to-start-and-stop-a-tomcat-service)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the sc command to set permissions on a specific service.

The format is a little difficult to understand, but first you will need to find the user or group's SID to use the command (something like "S-1-5-21-....").

```
sc myserver sdset spooler D:(A;;RPWP;;;place-sid-here)
```

A couple notes on that command:

- **RP** Allows service start
- **WP** Allows service stop

Replace *myserver* with your server's name and *spooler* with the service you want to edit.

More information is available at the following locations:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742037(WS.10).aspx

http://msmvps.com/blogs/erikr/archive/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows.aspx

Comment: Additionally you need to prefix the entires with D: [as per my answer here](http://serverfault.com/questions/184279/give-users-the-right-to-restart-a-service/184338#184338). In your example, this would be: sc myserver sdset spooler D:(A;;RPWP;;;place-sid-here)

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for my VMs to spin up, but it looks like this should work (from reading [this](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Controlling-Service-Security-Windows-Server-2008.html))

- Open group policy to Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\System Services
- Edit the service in question, enable "define policy setting" and then "edit security"
- Add the user and give them "read" and "start, stop, and pause" rights

I'll swing by after I've tried this out, but good question!  I had no idea this had been added.

This might also work:  [Remotely restarting a service for a non-administrator user](https://serverfault.com/questions/87806/remotely-restarting-a-service-for-a-non-administrator-user)

Comment: When i go Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings there is no System Services :-(

Comment: Hmm...maybe an R2/Win7 feature of Group Policy?  Unfortunately, I don't have a way to test downlevel but mine matches @Kara.

Comment: That's very odd!  You're on the domain controller, and it's 2008 server?

Comment: Ach, sounds like it's R2, bummer!

Comment: No i am not on the domain controller, i am on the server directly, because it's a custom service, install only on this machine.

Comment: now I wonder if there's  a way to add that custom service to the domain policy?  assuming you're able to edit GP.  Doug's answer seems more direct, though.  ;)

Comment: Doesn't work on Win2008 R2 - there is no "System Services" item.