# Give users the right to restart a service

Tags: windows, permissions, service

Based on [How to give rights to one user for the restart of a service](https://serverfault.com/questions/166641/how-to-give-rights-to-one-user-for-the-restart-of-a-service)

I've tried the command

```
sc sdset My.Service (A;;RPWP;;;S-1-1-0)
```

which i believe should give all users permission to restart My.Service

when I run the command

the error is:

```
[SC] ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor FAILED 87:    
wrong parameter
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
sc sdset My.Service D:(A;;RPWP;;;S-1-1-0)
```

sc succeeds, but net.exe and sc.exe gives permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prefix the entires with D: like this:

```
sc sdset My.Service D:(A;;RPWP;;;S-1-1-0)
```

Comment: SC says ok, but afterwards I get permission denied on 
    net start My.Service and sc delete My.Service . I've now removed said service from regedit, but obviously I am taking the wrong approach. It seems sc clears all previous permissions

Comment: Solution: sc sdshow My.Service => merge result with (A;;RPWP;;;S-1-1-0)

Comment: +1 You beat me to it :)